# Is it possible to streamline a given set of operators to any arbitrary set of classes?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, operators, factory-pattern

Consider the following set of classes and the relationship of their operators: We can implement them in two distinct ways. The first where the operators are defined within the class, and the latter where they are defined outside of the class...

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    T value;

    T& operator+(const A<T>& other) { return value + other.value; }
    // other operators
}; 

temlate<typename T>
struct B {
   T value;
   
   T& operator+(const B<T>& other) { return value + other.value; }
};

// Or...
template<typename T>
struct A {
    T value;
};
template<typename T>
T& operator+(const A<T>& lhs, const A<T>& rhs) { return lhs.value + rhs.value; }
// ... other operators

template<typename T>
struct B {
    T value;
};
template<typename T>
T& operator+(const B<T>& lhs, const B<T>& rhs) { return lhs.value + rhs.value; }  
// ... other operators
```

Is there any way in C++ where I would be able to make a single class or struct of operators to where I could simply be able to declare or define them within any arbitrary class C without having to write those same operators multiple times for each class? I'm assuming that the operators will have the same behavior and property for each distinct class that defines them considering that they will all follow the same pattern.

For example:

```
template<typename T, class Obj>
struct my_operators {
    // define them here 
};

// Then
template<typename T>
struct A {
    T value;
    my_operators ops;
};

template<typename T>
struct B {
    T value;
    my_operators ops;
};
```

Remember I'm restricting this to C++17 as I'm not able to use any C++20 features such as Concepts... If this is possible, what kind of method or construct would I be able to use, what would its structure and proper syntax look like? If this is possible then I'd be able to write the operators once and just reuse them as long as the pattern of the using classes matches without having to write those operators for each and every individual class...

Comment: I can think of a way to use SFINAE to define an operator overload for any class that defines an inner marker, as a typedef (similar how `is_transparent` identifies transparent comparators in C++14 and later). However, this feels like an XY problem. What problem are you trying to solve? No, not the one about making operator overloads work this way, but the problem to which the solution involves making operators work this way?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yeah, that's what I was struggling with... does this become an X/Y problem? .... If not, then how? And if so, it would be nice as you would have code reuse!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I appreciate your feedback since this will help me in the early stages with the design process and overall structure of my code base.

Comment: The other issue of concern is the "ambiguity" that the compiler might make upon compilation with template argument deduction...

Comment: The preprocessor has no involvement in template argument deduction.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik reworded specifying the compiler instead of preprocessor... My mistake there... Hope that makes more sense

Comment: Well, the rules for template argument deduction are very precise, so I don't know what ambiguity means here. In any case, you can look at how transparent comparators are implemented in C++14, how they work, and use it as a guide to build your own overloads.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I will have to check that out and do some research into `transparent comparators`...

Comment: I found this Youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBUacofxOP8 to be useful and helpful within the context of my design pattern above.

Comment: Trivial nitpick: Returning a `T&` for `operator+` seems a bit weird, since won't it be a reference to a local variable that immediately goes out of scope? Seems like it ought to return a `T`.

Comment: @NathanPierson True, I wasn't concerned about the "correctness" here where I'm more concerned about the overall design pattern!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using CRTP inheritance?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct base_op
 {
   auto operator+ (T const & o) const
    { return static_cast<T&>(*this).value + o.value; }
 };

template<typename T>
struct A : public base_op<A<T>>
 { T value; }; 

template<typename T>
struct B : public base_op<B<T>>
 { T value; }; 

int main()
 {
   A<int>   a1, a2;
   B<long>  b1, b2;

   a1.value = 1;
   a2.value = 2;

   std::cout << a1+a2 << std::endl;

   b1.value = 3l;
   b2.value = 5l;

   std::cout << b1+b2 << std::endl;
 }
```

Obviously this works only for template classes with a `value` member.

For the "outside the class" version, `base_op` become

```
template <typename T>
struct base_op
 {
   friend auto operator+ (T const & t1, T const & t2)
    { return t1.value + t2.value; }
 };
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP asks

> now I'm struggling to write their equivalent `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=` operators within this same context... Any suggestions?

It's a little more complicated because they must return a reference to the derived object... I suppose that (for example) `operator+=()`, inside `base_op`, could be something as

```
T & operator+= (T const & o)
 {
   static_cast<T&>(*this).value += o.value;

   return static_cast<T&>(*this);
 }
```

Comment: I think this might suit my needs. It would reduce a lot of code duplication where the operators of various classes all share the same set of properties within their overall design structure.

Comment: I took your suggestion of using CRTP in mind and came up with the following implementation that you can find in an answer that I provided only as a reference point. Let me know what you think... could there be any improvements, is there anything I'm missing or overlooking, or should I start a new Q/A and ask that there pointing to this Q/A?

Comment: Okay, I was able to implement the basic arithmetic operators such as `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/` in this fashion, however, now I'm struggling to write their equivalent `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=` operators within this same context... Any suggestions?

Comment: @FrancisCugler - About the code in your answer... I'm a little perplexed about the template version of the operators... there isn't the risk of collision? Anyway... for the `+=` (etc.) operators, answer improved; hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the edit max66 I'll have to look at that... I was thinking of adding a return reference to this base class... which can be seen in this pdf https://conradsanderson.id.au/misc/sanderson_templates_lecture_uqcomp7305.pdf with the correlation between the matrix and glue classes and how they inherit from a base class that has a return reference...

Answer (score 0):

Taking the answer provided by user max66 using `CRTP` and borrowing the concept of `transparent comparators` provided by the user SamVarshavchik within the comment section of my answer, I was able to adopt them and came up with this implementation design:

```
template<class T>
struct single_member_ops {
    friend auto operator+(T const & lhs, T const & rhs) 
    { return lhs.value + rhs.value; }
    friend auto operator-(T const & lhs, T const & rhs) 
    { return lhs.value - rhs.value; }

    template<typename U>
    friend auto operator+(T const& lhs, const U& rhs) 
    { return lhs.value + rhs.value; }

    template<typename U>
    friend auto operator-(T const& lhs, const U& rhs )
    { return lhs.value - rhs.value;}    
};

template<typename T>
struct A : public single_member_ops<A<T>>{
    T value;    
    A() = default;
    explicit A(T in) : value{in} {}
    explicit A(A<T>& in) : value{in.value} {}
    auto& operator=(const T& rhs) { return value = rhs; }
};

template<typename T>
struct B : public single_member_ops<B<T>> {
    T value;
    B() = default;
    explicit B(T in) : value{in} {}
    explicit B(B<T>& in) : value{in.value} {}
    auto& operator=(const T& rhs) { return value = rhs; }
};

int main() {
    A<int> a1(4);
    A<int> a2;
    A<int> a3{0};
    a2 = 6;
    a3 = a1 + a2; 

    B<double> b1(3.4);
    B<double> b2(4.5);

    auto x = a1 + b2;
    auto y1 = a2 - b2;
    auto y2 = b2 - a1;

    return x;
}
```

You can see that this will compile found within this example on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/zbT9ac).

The additional `templated operator` allows for different types: `A<T>` and `B<U>` to use the operators even if `T` and `U` are different for both `A` and `B` provided there is a default conversion between `T` and `U`. However, the user will have to be aware of truncation, overflow & underflow, and narrowing conversions depending on their choice of `T` and `U`.

Comment: Your template operator allows `A<char>() + B<int>()`. You might go for `template <template <typename> class C, typename T> struct single_member_ops;` to allows more control/restriction.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank You for the advice! I'm also having issues trying to implement the `op=` operators... within this base class... any suggestions there?

Comment: With above, you have also access to `T` for your `C<T>& operator =(const T&)`

Comment: @Jarod42 Okay, I'll have to check it out.

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried adding in the `class template` argument within the op struct, but now I'm getting compiler errors stating that my basic operators are not defined or not found... Would you be able to show an example of a single set of operators such as `+` and `+=` with your recommendation? It could just be a syntax issue that I'm struggling with, however, if I could see an example of it working, then I could build off of it and implement the rest of my operators... I would also like the `op=()` to be declared as a friend if possible...

Comment: @Jarod42 You can answer my question from the comments here on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65993024/1757805

Comment: What I was referring to, by citing transparent comparators, is how various container methods, like `find()` that take a forwarding reference that participates in overload resolution only if the comparator defines `is_transparent`. Similarly, your template classes can simply define `is_value_comparable`, and you define plain, garden variety, global operator overloads that use SFINAE to enable their participation in overload resolution only if the operands define `is_value_comparable`.

Comment: @FrancisCugler: I was though about something like [that](https://godbolt.org/z/TET53q) as I though you want more restriction, but it seems not now.

Comment: @Jarod42 Only in special cases where it makes sense sure such as adding an int to a char... however, adding a char to a char would be okay, but as for anything that can be explicitly converted without having to cast it, such as adding an int to a float dropping off the decimal bits after the addition, or adding a float to an int and preserving them, I would like to allow! So whatever is on the `LHS` of the operator should be the type that is returned... I haven't gotten to this part yet in my declarations... Just trying to get the CRTP code structure built first...