# Inheriting from a template class set of operators using CRTP

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, crtp, static-polymorphism

This is a follow-up from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65986508/1757805) Q/A.

I'm in the process of taking user Jarod42's advice by using `template <template<typename> class C, typename T>` instead of the example that I have shown as my answer to the question.

My code currently looks like this:

```
template<template<typename> class C, typename T>
struct single_member_ops {
    friend auto operator+(const C<T>& lhs, const C<T>& rhs) 
    { return lhs.value + rhs.value; }
    friend auto operator+(const C<T>& lhs, const T& rhs)
    { return lhs.value + rhs;}
    friend auto operator+(const T& lhs, const C<T>& rhs)
    { return lhs + rhs.value;}

    friend auto operator+=(const C<T> & lhs, const C<T> & rhs) {
        C<T> temp;
        temp.value = lhs.value + rhs.value;
        return temp.value;
    }

    friend auto operator+=(const C<T>& lhs, const T& rhs ) {
        C<T> temp;
        temp.value = lhs.value + rhs;
        return temp.value;
    }

    friend auto operator+=(const T& lhs, const C<T>& rhs) {
        C<T> temp;
        temp.value = lhs + rhs.value;
        return temp.value;
    }

};

template<typename T>
struct A : public single_member_ops<A<T>, T>{
    T value;    
    A() = default;
    explicit A(T in) : value{in} {}
    explicit A(A<T>& in) : value{in.value} {}
    auto& operator=(const A<T>& rhs) { return value = rhs; }
    auto& operator=(const T& rhs) { return value = rhs; }
};

template<typename T>
struct B : public single_member_ops<B<T>, T> {
    T value;
    B() = default;
    explicit B(T in) : value{in} {}
    explicit B(B<T>& in) : value{in.value} {}
    auto& operator=(const B<T>& rhs) {return value = rhs;}
    auto& operator=(const T& rhs) { return value = rhs; }
};

int main() {
    A<int> a1(4);
    A<int> a2;
    A<int> a3{0};
    a2 = 6;
    a3 = a1 + a2; 

    B<int> b1(5);
    B<int> b2(7); 

    B<double> bd1(3.4);
    B<double> bd2(4.5); 

    auto x1 = a1 + a2;
    auto x2 = a1 + b2;
    auto x3 = b1 + bd1;
    //auto y1 = a2 - b2;
    //auto y2 = b2 - a1;

    A<int> z;
    z += a2 + a3;

    return z.value;
}
```

You can see it on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/vdfaPn)

I'm only showing the `+()` and `+=()` operators to reduce the amount of code shown. I would prefer for all of my operators to be defined in this base class `single_member_ops` and to be a friend to all classes that will derive from this base class.

My code example above is generating compiler errors for the lines that the pertaining operator is not defined for the defined binary operator(s):

```
auto x2 = a1 + b2;
auto x3 = b1 + bd1;
```

It appears that I'm able to use the `+()` and `+=()` operators just fine for all types that match in both class and its type such as in `A<int>` and `A<int>` which is fine. However, let's say that I want to use them interchangeably such as in the following pseudo situations:

```
A<int> op A<double> 
A<int> op B<int>
A<int> op B<double>
```

What would I have to do, or what would my operators look like to achieve this? What else am I missing here?

Comment: My suggestion was mostly to avoid `A<int> op B<T>` :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 I want for each derived class to be able to use the operators but also to use them interchangeably... For example: `A<T>` +  `B<U>` where both `A` and `B` inherits from the base class of operators through the use of CRTP.

Comment: @Jarod42 I would also like for implicit conversion to take place, and for any specific type such as `char` that I don't want to use in this manner, I could also specialize the templates to default to some other action for that type...

Comment: @Jarod42 Take the GLM mathematics library for example... `glm::vec2 pos{3, 5}; glm::vec2 velocity{1.2f, 3.4f}; auto new_position = pos + velocity;` not exactly the same, but similar to that...

Comment: `A<T> op U` might be simpler then than using `A<T> op C<U>`.

Comment: @Jarod42 ... I know what templates are and for basic ones, they are simple enough to implement. However, they can become complex very quickly and it's usually either their syntax, the ambiguity they can generate when not done properly, or some other things that trip me up in the end... I don't struggle with the concepts, I struggle more with implementing them (declaring or defining) them with the proper syntax in order to achieve the appropriate design structure with the proper idioms in mind.